# Computing a Geometrical ratio $\frac{a}{b}$.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, golden-ratio

$XYZ$  is an equilateral triangle as shown on the image below.

The aim is to find the ratio $\frac{a}{b}$.

So far from the picture, it is easy to see that $b= \frac{YZ}{2}$.

Does anyone have an idea on how to find $b$ in term of $a$?

It seems from discussion with my classmates that this might lead to another geometrical interpretation of the Golden ratio.

[image]

Comment: How do you see $b=(yz)/2$? And, what does this have to do with the golden ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Another way to find the ratio
is to solve 
the $\triangle ROS$,
for which we know two sides and an angle:

\begin{align} 
\triangle ROS:\quad
|OR|&=r=\tfrac13\cdot2b\cdot\tfrac{\sqrt3}2
=\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,b
,\\
|OS|&=2r=\tfrac{2\sqrt3}3\,b
,\\
\angle SRO&=\angle ZRO+\angle SRZ=90^\circ+60^\circ
=150^\circ
,
\end{align}
so we can apply the cosine rule to get

\begin{align} 
|OS|^2&=|OR|^2+|RS|^2-2\cdot|OR|\cdot|RS|\cos\angle SRO
,\\
\tfrac43\,b^2&=
\tfrac13\,b^2+a^2-2\cdot\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,b\cdot a\cdot\cos150^\circ
,\\
\tfrac43\,b^2&=
\tfrac13\,b^2+a^2+2\cdot\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\,b\cdot a\cdot\cos30^\circ
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
b^2
-b\cdot a
-a^2
&=0
,\\
(\tfrac{b}a)^2
-
\tfrac{b}a
-1
&=0
,
\end{align}
which gives the answer (positive root) as

\begin{align} 
\frac{b}a
&=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
,
\end{align}

which is indeed the Golden ratio.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you compute OR?

Comment: @GuyFsone: $|OR|=r$ is the inradius of the equilateral triangle,
and as such it is equal to one third of the height 
and the circumradius $R$ is twice as big.
As far as the side $|XY|=|YZ|=|ZX|=2b$,
the height is $h=2b\sin60^\circ=\sqrt3\, b$,
then $|OR|=|OQ|=r=\tfrac{\sqrt3}3\, b$.

Answer (score 3):

Use the power of the point $R$ (or $Q$) with respect to the big circle.:

$$ (a+b)\cdot a = s^2$$

where $s= YZ/2$.

Note that since $QRX$ is equlateral we have $s=b$. Now write $q= b/a$ and we get$$ q^2-q-1=0\implies q={1\pm \sqrt{5}\over2}$$